# RelativeLayout embedded with another RelativeLayout causes onItemClickListener failure

Tags: android

I have set up a GridView to display a list of products. The grid works fine. When I use a single relativeLayout, it works great. However, when I add another RelativeLayout in the item XML to include additional details, the click listener will not be called.

The grid is defined, along with my click listener, as follows:

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.browse_devices);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,ShowProductDetail.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("SKU", skuList.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
```

My item description if I have just the title, a few subtitles and a product image, the click listener works fine and clicking a product causes ShowProductDetail activity to start. That definition is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@color/off_white" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/br_product_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/devil_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/br_product_subtitle0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/br_product_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/devil_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/br_product_subtitle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/br_product_subtitle0"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/devil_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/br_product_subtitle2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/br_product_subtitle1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/br_product_title"
    android:src="@drawable/separator_black" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/br_product_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

and looks like this:
[image]

But when I add the following XML to enable a user to select memory, color and quantity, the click listener is never called.   Here is the additional RelativeLayout I added to the bottom:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/br_product_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/off_white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/capacity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:text="@string/device_mem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/color_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/capacity_title"
        android:text="@string/device_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/color_title"
        android:text="@string/quantity" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/memory_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/capacity_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/capacity_title"
        android:layout_below="@id/capacity_title" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/color_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/color_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/color_title" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/quantity_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/quantity_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/quantity_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/memory_spinner"
        android:text="$199.99"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/quantity_spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/device_price"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_buy_now" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And should look like this:
[image]

Can anyone provide any information as to why the click listener should fail to be called simply by adding a second RelativeLayout to the items in a GridView?

Comment: So no errors on the log cat.  And oh yeah do you work for Samsung?

Comment: no to both. No errors, and no, I don't work for Samsung.  I work for a Telco who sells phones by Samsung, among others.

Comment: Is the spinner working? Try adding `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendents"` to the outer RelativeLayout

Comment: Ok got ya.  So why to relative layouts...why not use a linear inside of a relative.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendents" didn't help.   I did try putting a click listener on each item in the gridView and that works.  That may be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 2 LinearLayouts horizontal with equal weights on each child on both rows. This will work universal for all devices. A GridView will have disproportionate column widths on change of orientation and smaller devices.